# RubyRacer runtime is not defined in Rails 6.1.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to set up for running parallel RSpec in Rails 6. When I tried to run the command `rake parallel:create` to create the database for testing environment, I got error `ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: RubyRacer runtime is not defined`. I had no idea to fix it and I tried so many ways but not.

Anyone helps me to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Did your app working fine before adding parallel spec? Also

Comment: Right, my app is fine